# What does this error "SoapFaultClientException" mean?

Tags: java, spring, soap

I'm developing SOAP client after learning Spring official tutorial as an example: (https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)

For my project I have more complicated WSDL file.
I successfully generated classes then I created config class and the client class.

But I receive an error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at com.example.consumingwebservice.Client.getFineInfoById(Client.java:43)
```

What does this error mean?

Where can be a mistake?

What should I check?